# How to delete a server I added during creating a new "Dynamic Web Project" in MyEclipse?

Tags: myeclipse

I am using MyEclipse 2014 Professional.

I have just created a **"Web -> Dynamic Web Project"** just like in Eclipse. During the creation process, I have created a new Runtime called "Apache Tomcat v7.0.41". But after that, I cannot find a place to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

MyEclipse web projects should normally be created using New->Web Project or New->Other->MyEclipse->Java Enterprise Projects->Web Project. Dynamic web projects use the native functions of the eclipse web tools, rather than the functionality integrated into MyEclipse.

I'm not sure why you'd want to delete runtimes that you've configured into a project but they can be deleted by going to Window->Preferences->Server->Runtime Environments. If you've created a server with the runtime, open the WTP Servers (only available if you've enabled WTP Extras capability), view and delete the server from there.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Menu `Window ->` Click on `Preferences` option, then Expand `MyEclipse -> Servers -> Tomcat 7.x` Click on `Disable` radio button then Click on `Apply and OK` button. There is no delete option for delete Servers only options are `Enable and Disable` in MyEclipse.

How to remove / Disable servers from MyEclipse

**Screenshot:** Right click on Image and Click on **View Image**.

[image: How to remove servers from MyEclipse]

Before Disable Tomcat 7.x server in MyEclipse at `Servers show view`.

**Screenshot:**

[image: In Servers show view when Tomcat 7.x server enable]

After Disable Tomcat 7.x server in MyEclipse at `Servers show view`.

**Screenshot:**

[image: In Servers show view when Tomcat 7.x server disable]